# system () rsync with variable path with spaces

Tags: perl

I need to pass a variable path with spaces to Perl's `system` `rsync` command.  My script contains these variables:

```
$mht_user = "username";
$mht_share = "/mypath/with some space/01. continue/another space/";
$mht_dstpath = $mht_user.'@'.$mht_host.":".$mht_share."";
```

I need to pass the destination path to the `rsync` command

```
system ("/usr/bin/rsync -acz -H --delete /my source path ".$mht_dstpath.");
```

`rsync` does not like the path with that spaces, so I tried to write the path in this mode:

```
$mht_share = "/mypath/with\ \some\ \space/01.\ \continue/another\ \space/";
```

rsync accepts it, but it breaks the path into:

```
/mypath/with
```

How can I pass the path with spaces to rsync?

Comment: Have you tried splitting the arguments (to avoid running the command through sh, which does its own thing with white space in arguments): `system '/usr/bin/rsync', '-acz', '-H', '--delete, $path` ?

Comment: Maybe look into [File::Rsync](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Rsync) instead of running `rsync` directly?

Answer (score 4):

### Understanding the Issue

This is ultimately a shell issue. Let's `rsync` out of the loop to illustrate the problem

Here is a simple script, `printargs.pl`, that lists its arguments. We can use it to show what actually gets passed to a program when you run `system`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "[$_]\n" for @ARGV;
```

Now call it with some of the parameter list you are using

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $mht_user = "username";
my $mht_host = "host";
my $mht_share = "/mypath/with some space/01. continue/another space/";
my $mht_dstpath = $mht_user.'@'.$mht_host.":".$mht_share."";

system ("perl /tmp/echoargs.pl -acz -H --delete /my source path $mht_dstpath.");
```

output is

```
[-acz]
[-H]
[--delete]
[/my]
[source]
[path]
[username@host:/mypath/with]
[some]
[space/01.]
[continue/another]
[space/.]
```

Note that the shell has split `/my source path username@host:/mypath/with some space/01. continue/another space/.` on the embedded spaces

### Option1: Use Shell quoting

You can use the single-quotes to enclose the string with embedded spaces, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $mht_user = "username";
my $mht_host = "host";
my $mht_share = "/mypath/with some space/01. continue/another space/";
my $mht_dstpath = $mht_user.'@'.$mht_host.":".$mht_share."";

# Use single-quotes to enclose the string with embedded spaces 
system ("perl /tmp/echoargs.pl -acz -H --delete '/my source path $mht_dstpath.'");
```

output is

```
[-acz]
[-H]
[--delete]
[/my source path username@host:/mypath/with some space/01. continue/another space/.]
```

### Option 2: avoid using a shell

This if from the `system` documentation

> If there is more than one argument in LIST,
> or if LIST is an array with more than one value, starts the
> program given by the first element of the list with arguments
> given by the rest of the list.

The meaning of that slightly confusing sentence is -- if you pass the program name and its parameters to `system` as a Perl list, you will bypass the shell.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $mht_user = "username";
my $mht_host = "host";
my $mht_share = "/mypath/with some space/01. continue/another space/";
my $mht_dstpath = $mht_user.'@'.$mht_host.":".$mht_share."";

# pass parameters individually to bypass the shell
system ("perl", "/tmp/echoargs.pl",  "-acz",  "-H",  "--delete",  "/my source path $mht_dstpath.");
```

outputs

```
[-acz]
[-H]
[--delete]
[/my source path username@host:/mypath/with some space/01. continue/another space/.]
```

Comment: Option 2 is the better one, but for option 1, consider a module like [ShellQuote::Any](https://metacpan.org/pod/ShellQuote::Any) to do the quoting for you.